# Is it possible to connect two Duplex streams in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs, stream

I am using the `node:net` Socket API in a library I'm writing. I want to unit test this code, so I would like to abstract over Socket by allowing this unit to accept any Duplex stream.

For testing purposes, I would like to have a method of creating streams which allows me to mock/spy on both the 'local' and 'remote' sides, but this can be implemented easily if I am able to just create two connected streams.

I've tried a few methods of creating a Duplex class myself but have not quite been able to figure out how to pipe data between the two.

I hope for an API like this:

```js
const [local, remote] = createLinkedDuplexes();
local.write('abc');
remote.read(); // => 'abc'
remote.write('def');
local.read(); // => 'def'
```

From here I would then attach Jest mocks onto the `'data'` events from both sides and use those in my unit tests.

Any method of obtaining this?

Answer (score 0):

The NPM module [`stream-pair`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-pair) implements this with two `Side` duplex classes which pass data on a child property, `other`.